# Matrix- "Access violation writing location 0x00900B0C" - error in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I´ve got a problem with matrices. I wanted to have a simple Matrix and assign values depending on other values to it.

I want to have sth. like this:

```
      i -->                   // i is my x-value and j my y-value in the matrix
   j   25 25 25 25 25         // inital condition values
   |   27 26 25 .. ..         // filling the matrix with values depending on a 
   v   31 28 .. .. ..         // border condition, the inital values and neighbour values.
       .. .. .. .. ..         //and so on
```

I try to explain it with the code:

At first i define some variables and a matrix like

```
int Matrix[10][1000]; //<-- i´m not sure how to implement a dynamical matrix correctly
                         // so i just defined its size like this

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int iter=0;
int Iterator=1000;
```

In the next step i wanted to fill the matrix with Zero´s like:

```
for (i = 0; i <= size_X; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= size_Y; j++) {

        Matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

But it gives me here this error "Access violation writing location 0x00900B0C" yet.. and i don´t get why?

Furthermore my code looks like this to fill the first row of the matrix with inital values:

```
for (i = 0; i <= Size_X; i++) {

    Matrix[i][0] = 25;
```

But the main problem i suppose, and the main part of my code is fill-ins of the other cells of the matrix by iterating and refering also to neigbour cells in the Matrix:

```
do {

    for (j = 1; j <= Size_Y; j++) {

        Matrix[0][j] = Matrix[0][j - 1] + Fo*0.5*(2.0*Bi*(Umgebungstemperatur - Matrix[0][j - 1]) + 2.0*(Matrix[0 + 1][j - 1] - Matrix[0][j - 1]**) + 2.0*Bi*(Umgebungstemperatur - Matrix[0][j]) + 2.0*(Matrix[0 + 1][j] - Matrix[0][j]));
        Matrix[Size_X][j] = Matrix[Size_X][j - 1] + Fo*0.5*(2.0*Bi*(Umgebungstemperatur - Matrix[Size_X][j - 1]) + 2.0*(Matrix[Size_X - 1][j - 1] - Matrix[Size_X][j - 1]) + 2.0*Bi*(Umgebungstemperatur - Matrix[Size_X ][j]) + 2.0*(Matrix[Anzahl_dx- 1][j] - Matrix[Size_X][j]));

            for (i = 1; i < Size_X; i++) {
                Matrix[i][j] = Matrix[i][j - 1] + Fo*0.5*(Matrix[i - 1][j - 1] - 2.0*Matrix[i][j - 1] + Matrix[i + 1][j - 1] + Matrix[i - 1][j] - 2.0*Matrix[i][j] + Matrix[i + 1][j]);
            }

    }

    iter = iter + 1;

} while (iter != Iterator);
}
```

At last i just want to write the matrix into a .txt or .csv-file but it just gives me the first row with the correct values and the program breaks down after.

Comment: What is `size_X` and `size_Y` ?

Comment: it´s just the sizes of the matrix--> size_X=11 and size_Y=1001

Comment: I bet this is because you're using `<=` instead of `<` in your loops. Is there an index 11 in your matrix? No, there isn't.

Comment: Normally, for an array of size `n`, you would iterators from 0 to `n-1`, since arrays are 0 based in c++. `int x[10]` contains 10 elements, at indices 0 through 9. Do not increase the size by 1, do not iterate until `x[n]`.

Comment: If you declare a matrix like that: `int Matrix[10][1000]`, your maximum index access is: `Matrix[9][999]` because in C you count from **zero**. Also like the comment said before, your for loops are using `<=`.

Comment: yes i know that.. sry, i just exchanged it with the real variable i used, but this is not the mistake unfortunately.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is size_X and size_Y ?  (asked by me in a comment)

> it´s just the sizes of the matrix--> size_X=11 and size_Y=1001 (comment from Mattis Seehaus)

So in this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= size_X; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= size_Y; j++) {

        Matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

You'll try to access `Matrix[11][1001]`. That is outside your array and therefore an access violation. The last element of the array is `Matrix[9][999]`. So don't go above that when indexing it.

Normally you would do:

```
size_X = 10;
size_Y = 1000;
```

and change the loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < size_X; i++) {       // Just < instead of <=
    for (j = 0; j < size_Y; j++) {   // Just < instead of <=

        Matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

The same applies to other `for` loops.

Also you have this:

```
Matrix[Size_X][j] = Matrix[Size_X][j - 1] + Fo*0.5*(
       ^^^^^^
    // Again this is an access violation.
```

And another access violation:

```
        for (i = 1; i < Size_X; i++) {
            Matrix[i][j] = Matrix[i][j - 1] + Fo*0.5*(Matrix[i - 1][j - 1] - 2.0*Matrix[i][j - 1] + Matrix[i + 1][j - 1] + Matrix[i - 1][j] - 2.0*Matrix[i][j] + Matrix[i + 1][j]);
                                                                                                           ^^^^^
                                                                                           // Again this is an access violation. 

        }
```

Comment: okay thank you (all)! i think i´ll need to check my code again.. hopefully i´ll find all of the mistakes :D. thanks again :).

Comment: I fixed this issue by starting a new project and i don´t have any clue why it works right now, but thanks to you all! i found some more mistakes thanks to you! :)! really a great forum here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `size_X` and `size_Y` are defined.

Also it's going out of bounds here:

```
for (i = 0; i <= size_X; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= size_Y; j++) {

        Matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

You should be using `<` instead of `<=` when iterating your loops.

Comment: @Link OP has elaborated in the question's comments that `size_X` and `size_Y` are `11` and `1001` respectively and that they should represent the size of the matrix. Perhaps you can complete your answer with that information.